# How to get the second highest number from an array?

Tags: swift

I have two arrays:

```
var arrPrice = [500, 400, 300, 300, 200, 100, 100]
var arrId = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

I need the output for id 1 price should be 400, for id 2 price should be 300, for id 3 price should be 200, for id 4 price should be 200, for id 5 price should be 200, for id 6 price should be 100 and last id and price should be same like for id 7 price should be 100. How do I get the values like these.

Comment: try this `let arrPrice = [500, 400, 300, 300, 200, 100, 100].sorted().f
        let farray = arrPrice.filter {$0 != arrPrice.max()}`

Comment: `let secondMax = Set(arrPrice).sorted().dropLast().last`, maybe.

Comment: What is the logic? The values in the array are 400, 300, 300, 200, 100, 100 but in the text you are talking about 400, 300, 200, 200, 200, 100.

Comment: @holex thanx a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try a [Sort](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2945003-sorted)

Please add some code what you've tried and I can edit this post with further help.  Although this seems like this is a CS100 assignment early in the semester. :P